# Get Role parameter as Viewbag from controller and get in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-ajax

I have controller where I send role parameter as true or false to js

Controller (relevant code):

```
 public ActionResult GetForEdit()
        {

            var userRole = User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin");
            @ViewBag.Role = userRole;

            return Content(result, "application/json");
        }
```

There I get `true` or `false` into `@Viewbag`

Ajax to call controller:

```
function GetModulLogWasteForEdit() {
    debugger;
    currentId = 0;
    var manifest = $('#manifest').val();
    $('#save').removeClass('hidden');

    try {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "get",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/Log/GetForEdit", // controller
                data: { manifest: manifest },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: onGetModulLogWasteSuccess,
                error: function (response) {
                    ErrorMessage("Error", GetTextError(response));
                }
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        ErrorMessage("Error", e.message);
    }
}
```

and now I populate kendo Grid to show fields, and there is where I want to use my viewbag so:

```
function onGetModulLogWasteSuccess(response) {
    var role = '@ViewBag.Role'; // there I get my role bool

    $("#lstInfo").kendoGrid({....

        {
                    field: "", title: "Actions", width: "120px", hidden: role,
                    template: function (item) {

                        var id = item.Id;
                        var dropbox = "<div><div class='btn btn-danger'><a class='light' href='javascript:RemoveLogWaste(" + id + ");' role='button'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i> Delete</a></div></div>";
                        return dropbox;

                    }
```

As you can see I use `hidden:role` parameter, but it always come true, when controller get it to false it hidden field too, Help is very appreciated. Regards

Update:

As Stephen answer, I change my controller to:

```
 public ActionResult GetForEdit(string manifest)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            var userRole = User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin");

            try
            {
                result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(LogWasteModule.GetForEdit(manifest));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                result,
                role = userRole,
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            });
        }
```

GetForedith class:

```
 public static List<LogEdit_Result> GetForEdit(string manifest)
    {
        var result = new List<LogEdit_Result>();

        using (var context = new EF.A())
        {
            result = context.LogEdit(manifest).ToList();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But I get

> his request has been blocked because sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the ViewBag from client-side javascript.

It is only available server-side(i.e. in your View/cshtml).

In order to do what you are trying to do, you will need to put the userRole value into the "result" that you are returning and then you will have it client-side, i.e.

```
public ActionResult GetForEdit()
{
    var userRole = User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin");
    // ...fill result (not shown)

    return Json(new {
        result = result,
        role = userRole
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And then

```
function onGetModulLogWasteSuccess(response) {
    var role = response.role;
    // response.result contains the "result" var from the server action.

    $("#lstInfo").kendoGrid({....
}
```

The reason your role var is always true is because the string '@ViewBag.Role' is *really* the string '@ViewBag.Role' NOT the contents of the ViewBag(which again is not available client-side), and this string is truthy(evaluates as true when you ask it to be a boolean).

**After Question Updated**

Change your action to

```
public ActionResult GetForEdit(string manifest)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        var userRole = User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin");

        try
        {
            result = LogWasteModule.GetForEdit(manifest);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return Json(new
        {
            result = result,
            role = userRole,
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

because

1. you shouldn't need to manually serialize your result as Json() will do it
2. the syntax of your Json(new...) is wrong: you need to use "field = value" syntax, NOT just "value" and the AllowGet needs to be a parameter to Json() NOT a value you add to the object.

Comment: I get: "his request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party" ... so I add into `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` into return Json statement, but I continue getting sensitive information issue

Comment: Can you show your new server action?  Adding the AllowGet should have worked...I just tested it a local test project.  I've also updated my answer to include it.

Comment: I update my question with current controller and class, my sintax of JsonRequest was wrong

Comment: I have a trouble, can you help me?